# Stream binary part of a message from BizTalk orchestration

Tags: streaming, biztalk, mtom, biztalk-2009

I must send a MTOM request to a WCF service that expects the following schema as input:

```
<xs:complexType name="BinaryRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="requestContent" nillable="true" type="BinaryRequestContent" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="BinaryRequest" nillable="true" type="BinaryRequest" />
  <xs:complexType name="BinaryRequestContent">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="partData" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="partNumber" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="transactionId" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="BinaryRequestContent" nillable="true" type="BinaryRequestContent" />
```

As you can see the "partData" property is of type byte[] and I would like to have the posibility to stream it and send it in a separated MIME part.

Using the example from http://seroter.wordpress.com/biztalk-and-wcf-part-iv-attachment-patterns/ is not possible because my binary data is only a part of the response.

Any idea how to do this?
I have a test solution but the binary content is send inline as base64 not separated as an attachment
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1M277-_UZ35Si1JWWw5Nm9ia0E/edit?usp=sharing